# Access lenovo ideapad (z580) bios with ubuntu installed

Tags: lenovo, bios

ubuntu seems to block my access to the bios of my system.

I know this for sure since this problem occur only since I installed ubuntu (12.10). while the system is booting, pressing F2 leads me to grub.

How may I access my bios?

Answer (score 0):

Press and hold F2, then power on. Mine has Windows 8 preinstalled with UEFI boot.